# Unused function changes performances

Tags: c++, performance, gcc

While trying to estimate the difference of performances between `push_back` and `std::inserter` I run into a very strange performance issue.

Let's consider the following code :

```
#include <vector>
using container = std::vector<int>;
const int size  = 1000000;
const int count = 1000;

#ifdef MYOWNFLAG
void foo(std::insert_iterator<container> ist)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        *ist++ = i;
}
#endif

void bar(container& cnt)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        cnt.push_back(i);
}
int main()
{
    container cnt;
    for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        cnt.clear();
        bar(cnt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, no mather whether or not `MYOWNFLAG` is defined, the function foo isn't called. However the value of this flag has an impact on the perfomances:

```
$ g++ -g -pipe -march=native -pedantic -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -o bin/inserter src/inserter.cc && time ./bin/inserter
./bin/inserter  4,73s user 0,00s system 100% cpu 4,728 total

$ g++ -g -pipe -march=native -pedantic -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -o bin/inserter src/inserter.cc -DMYOWNFLAG && time ./bin/inserter
./bin/inserter  2,09s user 0,00s system 99% cpu 2,094 total
```

Note that if I change the protopyte of `foo` to use `std::back_insert_iterator` I get a similar performance as if I had not set the flag.

What's going on with the compiler's optimisations ???

### EDIT

I use gcc 4.9.2 20150304 (prerelease)

### Repoduced

- reproduced by stefan on ideone
- reproduced by me on another machine with gcc 4.9.2
- not reproduced by me on another machine with gcc 4.6.3 and flag -std=c++0x

Comment: Did you have a look at the assembly?

Comment: Can not reproduce with GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: I'm not good enough to understand it, particularly with -03

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. My wild guess is some sort of caching issue (the libraries, perhaps). Are those timings reproducible, or does the slow run only happen the first time?

Comment: in this code, you always call `bar` because the call site is not surrounded by `#ifdef`

Comment: @TemplateRex He knows: "no matter whether or not MYOWNFLAG is defined, the function foo isn't called. However [...]"

Comment: @orlp Good to know. Can someone reproduce it ?

Comment: I can reproduce on ideone: http://ideone.com/ELdNQp (3.5s vs 4.2s)

Comment: It looks like the additional function and the templates it instanciates prevented your optimizer from prooving something, whatever that may have been. An alternative explanation would be that the presence of the additional function tipped some heuristic, which essentially boils down to the same thing. But we are solidly in the territory of guesses here.

Comment: Can not reproduce using GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: Does the optimization level `-Os` show the same behavior? If it does, it might be a good idea to post the output of `gcc -S -Os`, it could be enlightening to some of the experts here... Please don't show the output of `gcc -S -O3` though, it's likely impossible to read anyway.

Comment: It's a very strange manifestation of a performance bug: if I use `i + 1` or `0` or whatever instead of `i` in the assignment in `foo`, the performance does not degrade. http://ideone.com/U2UGdn Nice find :D

Comment: @cmaster with `-Os` I also get variations (~5,1s without flag vs ~4,0s with flag)

Comment: @stefan, Same here, modifying (even sligtly) `foo` removes the behaviour, even if I apply similar changes to `bar`

Comment: Could be related to code alignment (may have implications on caching / decode bandwidth). Does it change if you add some inlined NOPs before your code?

Comment: @Leeor, making any (or both) of the function `inline` removes the gap in performance ...

Comment: Not the functions, try adding NOPs to move the address alignment of the main loop (you can use inline assembly for that).

Comment: I dont undestand ... how would I do that ? do I have to edit the assembly ?

Comment: I don't see any significant difference with g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: Can you show assemply? (most readable form: `g++ -pipe -march=native -pedantic -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -S -fverbose-asm -masm=intel -o inserter.s inserter.cc -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm`). Because I don't see significant enough differences with gcc explorer, but it may be not reproducting the issue

Comment: For some reason gcc decides to inline the call to `push_back` if the flag is defined. The inlining probably unlocks a whole lot of optimization opportunities, because now the compiler can see the strategy used by `push_back` to do the reallocations... You can test this using -finline-limit=100000, that basically forces the inline regardless of the flag. Anyway changing `*ist++ = i` with `*ist++ = 0` still has an effect, even with the forced inlines. There is probably another actor playing here, not just the inlining.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First I will show you magical trick how to achieve this without garbage function. Then I will show you why garbage function works. So trick:

Original ineffective (note my machine about twice faster):

```
g++ -g -pipe -march=native -pedantic -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -o bin/inserter src/inserter.cc --param inline-unit-growth=200 && time ./bin/inserter
real    0m2.197s
user    0m2.200s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Now goes trick (your define is still inactive):

```
g++ -g -pipe -march=native -pedantic -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -o bin/inserter src/inserter.cc --param inline-min-speedup=2 && time ./bin/inserter
real    0m1.114s
user    0m1.100s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Note: difference is in strange-looking argument `--param inline-min-speedup=2`

Now I will briefly outline investigation:

1. What is difference between fast and slow? In slow version we do have ineffective call to `emplace_back_aux` inside `bar()`, that is magically inlined when your foo is uncommented. So we may conclude, that bar is very hot and inlining is crushial here. And most probably all this bug is about inlining.
2. Now with option `-fdump-ipa-inline-details` lets look at inlining dumps. You will see different time/size considerations. It is hard to read and I don't want to paste here all details. But general result of studying this information: GCC thinks, that growth in module size (in percents) is not worth estimated speedup.
3. What to do? Two possibilities:

   3.1. Either increase module size and overall speedup estimations with unused `foo` code, that is using correct types like insert_iterator to call emplace_back and move ratio to be bigger and hit inlining limit (note that this way is very unstable -- everything may explode in other compiler versions with improved inlining algorithms, and you also need to be really lucky to guess the code to work).

   3.2. Or move inlining limit. What did I said to GCC with parameter provided is "consider for inlining even big functions with less speedup please".

That is. There are a lot of other parameters inside GCC and other tricks that you may do with them.

Comment: ok, why inlining `emplace_back_aux ` makes difference? Because it is called ~20 times on 1000,000 insertions - when container changes size, that grows exponentially.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I would have never suspected that. Also, what is your CPU ? I'm guessing it's a desktop and as I plan to update mine soon, those performance looks nice (my timming are on a i7 4702HQ)

Comment: Tbh i do not consider this answer complete... it fails to explain *why* `emplace_back_aux` unlocks the performance increase. Also i still have a  significant (~25%) difference with/without the flag even with --param inline-min-speedup=2. See [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/140f71fe8b21730e)