# Rarely used function that is unused affecting the performance

Tags: c, performance, gcc, optimization

There is an essential function in the program that is rarely used. However, I found out that even when this function is not used in a particular execution, this function causes an increase in runtime overhead.

For detailed explanation...

Below code is my very best attempt at writing a minimal example to show what I mean, but I apologize in advance if it doesn't make sense. I'm working in a minimal space of C language, so if the code looks pretty unoptimized, that is because I have no choice :( (I am very open to any suggestions, of course)

```
// extra_function.c
int extra_array[6] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
void copy_array(int *array, int num) {
  switch (num) {
  case (0):
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            array[i] = extra_array[i];
            break;
  }
}
```

```
// main.c
#include "extra_function.c"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int target_array[10] = {0};
  int copy_check = 0;
  if (argc == 2) {
    copy_check = 1;
  }

  // high runtime overhead
  if (copy_check == 1) {
    copy_array (target_array, 0);
  }

  // never used
  if (false) {
    copy_array (target_array, 0);
  }
}
```

To summarize, basically, I need to use a function `copy_array` instantiated outside of `main.c` to copy a statically allocated array from `extra_function.c` into `main.c`.

From looking at `main.c`, a condition `argc == 2` must happen for `copy_check` variable to become 1, otherwise `copy_array` function will never be called.

In my scenario, `argc == 2` condition **will never happen**.

However, it seems that because there is a *possibility* that `argc == 2` condition can happen, runtime overhead increases even though this condition never occurs.

**Why is this happening?** Is it because even though a function may never be called in this execution, there is some sort of initialization done underneath that causes the runtime overhead?

I was able to find this out because by making the function not used (as shown in `// never used`), I was able to save a runtime overhead.

Please let me know if my question is unclear, I understand that this question may sound ridiculous, but I have been trying to figure out why this is happening, but to no avail.

Here is a similar question: [Unused function changes performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154615/unused-function-changes-performances), but this seems like it is regarding solely **unused function** while my question is regarding **rarely used function unused**.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: "In my scenario, `argc == 2` condition will never happen." is unclear.  Nothing in code forbids that.   The compiler does not know  `argc == 2` will never occur.

Comment: **"argc == 2 condition will never happen."** - the compiler cannot possibly make this assertion. It would be incorrect if it did so.

Comment: In the `if (false)` case, the compiler can prove that `copy_array` is never used in `main`, hence `target_array` is an unused variable, hence the whole array can be eliminated. In the `argc` version, the compiler can't prove anything so it has to allocate an array. If the array is significantly larger in your "real" program, then this carries significant overhead as opposed to the version that can omit the array entirely.

Comment: What sort of runtime overhead (space, execution time, etc.)? How much additional overhead does this cause, compared to not having it?

Comment: What causes the overhead? Initialization or memory allocation? If target_array is not used you can skip initialization e.i  use `int target_array[10];` instead of `int target_array[10] = {0};`

Comment: If `target_array` is allocated on the heap in your "real" program, you can define a pointer only and do the memory allocation in `copy_array` if needed. Defining a pointer only `int* target_array=nullptr;` definitely will not cause overhead.

Comment: Did you compare the generated assembly?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses; they were very insightful and helped me understand the root of the problem. @Laci you were exactly right; that change you suggested definitely helped out solving this problem. Now that I think back, that was very silly of me to initialize an array, then wonder, "why am I getting an initialization overhead?". Thanks again everyone

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm runtime overhead was regarding execution time, I apologize that I didn't make this part clear in the question. Thanks to Laci, I was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because even though a function may never be called in this
> execution, there is some sort of initialization done underneath that
> causes the runtime overhead?

Runtime overhead is caused by initialization of `target_array`. If `target_array` is not used you can skip its initialization e.i use `int target_array[10];` instead of `int target_array[10] = {0};`

If `target_array` is allocated on the heap in your "real" program, you can define a pointer only and do the memory allocation in `copy_array` if needed. Defining a pointer only `int* target_array=nullptr;` definitely will not cause overhead.

Comment: @Jay I have copied my comments to an answer, please accept it and others can see that your issue is solved.